# How to use crontab to set setuid for executable file and unset it after run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

How to use crontab to set setuid for executable file and unset it after run

Because use root to run crontab  can not run executable file
But I only expect executable file has setuid on demand

Comment: Are you running the executable as root, or as another user?

Comment: Cron runs with a very limited PATH.  Try using the full path to the executable in the crontab.

Comment: I had already used full path, use root to set cron Job can not run Perl which not full path on a full path Perl script , so far I use setuid at  Perl script and bash script which have command to use Perl to run Perl script , I am not sure 4555 has security issue because hardening guide told me not to use setuid , but I just want to send email when some kind of syslog generated